# slick - dynamic filtering list of options

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I have scala project with slick.
I have two tables user and user devices:
The relation between tables is one to many

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
(
  id      UUID    NOT NULL,
  name    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_devices
(
  id           UUID NOT NULL,
  user_id      UUID NOT NULL,
  device_name  VARCHAR,
  device_model VARCHAR
);
```

I need to do such query in slick:

```
SELECT * FROM audience.user as u
JOIN user_devices on(u.id=user_devices.user_id)
where (device_name = 'Samsung' and device_model = 'A20')
   OR device_name = 'Xaomi'
;
```

this is my scala code

object Example extends App {

```
  case class UserRow(id: UUID, name: String, surname: String)
  case class UserDevices(id: UUID,
                         userId: UUID,
                         deviceName: Option[String],
                         deviceModel: Option[String])
  case class Params(deviceName: Option[String], deviceModel: Option[String])
  case class FilterBy(params: Option[List[Params]])
```

final class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends TableUserRow {

```
def id = column[UUID]("id")
def name = column[String]("name")
def surname = column[String]("surname")

def * = (id, name, surname).mapTo[UserRow]
```

}

final class UserDevicesTable(tag: Tag)
      extends TableUserDevices {

```
def id = column[UUID]("id")
def userId = column[UUID]("user_id")
def name = column[Option[String]]("device_name")
def model = column[Option[String]]("device_model")

def * = (id, userId, name, model).mapTo[UserDevices]
```

}

```
  def filter(filterBy: FilterBy): Future[Seq[UserRow]] = {

    val query = userTable
      .joinLeft(userDevicesTable)
      .on(_.id === _.userId)
      .filterOpt(filterBy.params) {
        case ((user: UserTable, userDevice: Rep[Option[UserDevicesTable]]),
              params:Seq[Params]) =>
          ???
      }
      .map(_._1)
      .result

    db.run(query)
  }
}
```

How I can filter with Or between Params obj, and how I can filter between params in Param obj with AND?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea for this situation is:

1. to map your `List[Params]` into a Slick condition; and then
2. combine all the conditions together with an AND or OR (via `reduceLeft`).

Here's a basic example:

```scala
val params =
 Params(Some("Samsung"), Some("A20")) ::
 Params(Some("Xaomi"),   None) ::
 Nil

// This is not quite complete, but a starting point:
val query = userTable.filter(row =>
  params
   .map { case Params(name, model) => row.name === name && row.model === model }
   .reduceLeft(_ || _)
)
```

Notice that we're turning each `Params` into a Slick conditional (here we're ANDing together two conditions). Then we're joining each condition togehter in the `reduceLeft` with an `||`.

That query will produce SQL along the lines of:

```sql
select 
  "device_name", "device_model" 
from 
  "devices" 
where 
   (("device_name" = 'Samsung') and ("device_model" = 'A20')) 
or (("device_name" = 'Xaomi')   and ("device_model" = null))
```

That's not quite right because of the `=== null` comparison. There are various ways to resolve that, but one is to pattern match on the various cases:

```scala
val query =
  userTable.filter(row =>
    params
      .collect {
        case Params(Some(name), None)  => row.name === name
        case Params(None, Some(model)) => row.model === model
        case Params(Some(name), Some(model)) => row.name === name && row.model === model
      }
      .reduceLeft(_ || _)
    )
```

I've used `collect` to avoid the expected non-exhaustive pattern match.

That query would produce:

```sql
where 
    ( ("device_name" = 'Samsung') and ("device_model" = 'A20') )
 or ("device_name" = 'Xaomi')
```

I have a demonstration repository containing AND and OR examples: https://github.com/d6y/list-of-tuples/tree/master/src/main/scala